# React Native Component Exception: undefined is not an object (evaluating_useContext.isAuthenticated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jsx

Im trying to authenticate a user and pull in context from another file. I feel like what Im doing is pretty straight forward but I keep getting the same error. Am I importing useContext wrong?

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";

import { AppNavigator } from "./app.navigator";
import { AccountNavigator } from "./account.navigator";

import { AuthenticationContext } from "../../services/authentication/authentication.context";

export const Navigation = () => {
  const { isAuthenticated } = useContext(AuthenticationContext);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isAuthenticated ? <AppNavigator /> : <AccountNavigator />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};
```

The Context per a request from a user below to help provide more information

```
import React, { useState, createContext } from "react";
import * as firebase from "firebase";

import { loginRequest } from "./authentication.service";

export const AuthenticationContext = createContext();

export const AuthenticationContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const onLogin = (email, password) => {
    setIsLoading(true);
    loginRequest(email, password)
      .then((u) => {
        setUser(u);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        setError(e);
      });
  };

  return (
    <AuthenticationContext.Provider
      value={{
        user,
        isLoading,
        error,
        onLogin,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AuthenticationContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: what is exported from `../../services/authentication/authentication.context`?

Comment: Hello Robin! Will update the post with this info right now

Comment: thanks. So you're not passing anything in to the `createContext` call so `useContext` will return `undefined`. It seems you need your context to be an object with an `isAuthenticated` property.

Comment: Oh OK, I'll put this as an answer [EDIT: now done]. Didn't know if it would be enough - thought it was more of a prod in the right direction rather than an "actual answer", it's something I still struggle to decide after a few years of being active on SO! Glad I helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing anything in to the `createContext` call here:

```
export const AuthenticationContext = createContext();
```

so `useContext(AuthenticationContext)` will return `undefined`. Therefore it will throw this error when you try to destructure and read an `isAuthenticated` property. It seems you need your context to be an object with an `isAuthenticated` property.

You might find it helpful to read the basics of React context [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), and specifically about `useContext` [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecontext).

Comment: thank you for the answer!